# WM_MOUSEMOVE message handling

Tags: c, winapi, wndproc

I have the following `WndProc`:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM w, LPARAM l)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
            return 0;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, w, l);
    }
}
```

I want to prevent the the mouse from moving, so that I am attempting to discard moving message. The problem is that mouse is still moving. I have tried also `WM_NCHITTEST` and `WM_MOUSEHOVER`.

Comment: You'll need a hook for that: [SetWindowsHookEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: I found an old C++ one and changed it a bit. It worked when I compiled this in C++, just causing the mouse to be unusable until the program ends: http://pastebin.com/GyANfGtZ. It's not the best you can do, but it'll get you started. Take care when using them.

Comment: I guess a bit of a hackier way to do it is to just spam `SetCursorPos` calls if it's just playing around. I'd never recommend doing anything near that in real code.

Comment: The hook code that @chris posted is quite wrong, to the point of being utterly useless as an example. For starters, as the documentation for the [`LowLevelMouseProc` callback function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644986.aspx) notes, the hook procedure *must* call the [`CallNextHookEx` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644974.aspx). On a more general note, please re-consider using a global solution to solve a local problem.

Comment: @CodyGray, The whole point of my sample was to disable the mouse completely. That involves not passing the event on. `It may return a nonzero value to prevent the system from passing the message to the rest of the hook chain or the target window procedure.` The second part is definitely a good point, having remembered about `ClipCursor`, though. My mind was set more in "having fun" mode than "distributing program" mode as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are trying to confine the cursor movement, please take a look at the [ClipCursor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648383%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function in the Windows API.

Comment: `ClipCursor` sounds like exactly what he's looking for. Do make sure, though, that you *release* the cursor by calling `ClipCursor` again to relinquish control to other applications. Completely taking over the user's computer and preventing them from using other applications is a user-hostile experience, guaranteed to get your app uninstalled immediately (if they can figure out how to open Control Panel).

Comment: Oh wow, I completely forgot about this function. Human memory fails.

Answer (score 7):

The `WM_MOUSEMOVE` message is just the window manager telling you *that the mouse has moved* and if your application wants to do something with that information it can do so. It is *not* a mechanism where you can intercept mouse movements and cancel them at will.